# Error in Node.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

Node started to return this to me when I create a new react native project.

In the project folder there is only:

```
'- (folder) node_modules
'- (file) package.json
'- (file) package-lock.json
```

[image]

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: Node Version 10.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is wrong. Either remove the word `type` or if you are trying to get default [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) from the './command' file then put the comma after the type.

`import type, {CommandT} from './commands';`

Comment: Hi.It is not me who performs this command.
I just run: react-native init MyProject